# How to create facet_grid on timeseries data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-grid

I have a dataset like this:

[image]

I want to show the trend, the x-axis containing the year values and the y-axis the corresponding values from the columns, so Maybe

```
 ggplot(data,aes(year,bm))
```

I want to not just plot one column but Maybe more of them. As in one plot it seems to be too much detailed I wanted to make use of facet_grid to arrange the plots nicely next to eacht other. However It did not work for my data as I think I have no 'real' objects to compare.
Does anyone has an idea how to I can realize facet_grid so it loos like something like this (in may case p1=BM and p2=BMSW):

[image]

Comment: please provide reproducible example, as well as the code you'd used for your plots above. seems like you'd run a smoother with errors.

Comment: You will need to melt your data into a long format (`tidyr::gather()`) and then use the new variable in `facet_wrap()` (or `facet_grid`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your data format. Here is an example with some fake data

```
library(tidyverse)

##Create some fake data
set.seed(3)
data <- tibble(
    year = 1991:2020,
    bm = rnorm(30),
    bmsw = rnorm(30),
    bmi = rnorm(30),
    bmandinno = rnorm(30),
    bmproc = rnorm(30),
    bmart = rnorm(30)
)

##Gather the variables to create a long dataset
new_data <- data %>%
    gather(model, value, -year)

##plot the data
ggplot(new_data, aes(x = year, y = value)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
    facet_grid(~model)
```

[image]